# What kind of purple flower is this?

Tags: species-identification, botany, flowers

Shot in a garden in Haliburton, Ontario, Canada on June 18th, 2020. Flowerhead size approx. 1 1/4" diameter across. [image]

Comment: Identifications questions should also include: 1) habitat information — e.g. was this growing in a marsh? were there any other plants nearby that you could identify?; and 2) an estimate of the size of the organism. Please [edit] your post to include this essential information. ——— Also note that such questions should be given the species-identification tag and that thanks/signatures etc. should not be included in SE posts.

Comment: fyi, Google Lens is pretty good at identifying plants.

Comment: How nice it would be if all images of flowers were stereographic like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9bgv.jpg) (from [here](https://archive.is/wip/cPfCj)). =)

Answer (score 9):

That looks like it could be a cultivar of [*Geranium sanguineum* (Bloody crane's-bill or Bloody geranium)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geranium_sanguineum) or something closely related.

[image: Geranium sanguinem, flowers & plants]

Image source: [Keith Weller, USDA Agricultural Research Service, Bugwood.org](https://www.forestryimages.org/browse/detail.cfm?imgnum=1322085) — [CCA3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/us/).

Some features that are consistent with this id are: the five identical bilobed petals, flower size and shape, hairy stems, and leaf form (palmate with five lobes each with three large 'teeth'). The flower features I can distinguish rule out related genera such as *Pelargonium* and *Erodium*, which have flowers that are not radially symmetrical. If this is a *Geranium*, then there should be 10 free stamens and the stigma should have a style with 5 branches.

This species is cultivated and typically blooms from June to August, which fits your described location and time.